# Microsoft Cognitive Video face tracking APIs returns sometimes weird results

Tags: video, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

Face tracking service returns ID of faces found inside the video.

If the video contains multiple cuts of different persons appearing one after the other, sometimes it happens they are registered under the same ID, also if they are different persons.

Assigning two different IDS to the same person is a much more tolerable behaviour than confusing faces.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem? Or is it a known bug?

Comment: What does Microsoft support say?

Comment: @szatmary yes as you can see here below. Anyway if you want you can upvote my request: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/356325-apis/suggestions/15830215-video-face-tracking-api-doesn-t-work-well-if-the-v

Answer (score 1):

I'm a member of the Cognitive Services team. The current algorithm is optimized for the case where the input comes from a single camera, with no cuts. As a result, cuts in the video might cause confusion between faces.

We are investigating improvements to the algorithm, but please feel free to add/upvote your specific issue on our [UserVoice forum](https://cognitive.uservoice.com)